# Binding window items to resource properties

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, resources

I have a WPF test window, in that window I declare a window resource and I want to bind the datacontext of the window to a dependency property on that resource object. Here is my example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"

        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:diagnostics="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
        >

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:TestObj x:Key="MyResObj" Target="{Binding DataContext, diagnostics:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" />
    </Window.Resources> 

    <Grid>
        <TextBox Tag="{StaticResource MyResObj}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and the code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.DataContext = this;

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

and here is my TestObj:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class TestObj : DependencyObject
    {

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Target", typeof(object), typeof(TestObj));

        public object Target
        {
            get { return this.GetValue(TargetProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TargetProperty, value); }
        }

    }
}
```

this is a simplified example I want to ultimately bind more complex things from the window to items declared in the Window.Resources section. Currently this is not working as I expect so I enabled verbose binding logging - the binding error I get is

> System.Windows.Data Warning: 54 : Created BindingExpression (hash=38018250) for Binding (hash=40782967)
>   System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 :   Path: 'DataContext'
>   System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 : BindingExpression (hash=38018250): Default mode resolved to OneWay
>   System.Windows.Data Warning: 59 : BindingExpression (hash=38018250): Default update trigger resolved   to PropertyChanged
>   System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=38018250): Attach to WpfApplication16.TestObj.Target (hash=39268741)
>   System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=38018250): Use Framework mentor 
>   System.Windows.Data Warning: 65 : BindingExpression (hash=38018250): Resolving source
>   System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=38018250): Framework mentor not found
>   System.Windows.Data Warning: 63 : BindingExpression (hash=38018250): Resolve source deferred
>   'WpfApplication16.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework.Aero\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.Aero.dll'
>   System.Windows.Data Warning: 65 : BindingExpression (hash=38018250): Resolving source
>   System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=38018250): Framework mentor not found
>   System.Windows.Data Warning: 65 : BindingExpression (hash=38018250): Resolving source  (last chance)
>   System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=38018250): Framework mentor not found
>   System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext; DataItem=null; target element is 'TestObj' (HashCode=39268741); target property is 'Target' (type 'Object')

Is it even possible to bind window items to resources like this? Or have I made a mistake with my binding?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can bind to a root object in its own resources (but don't quote me on it). Can you try binding the child grid to it instead?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:TestObj x:Key="MyResObj" Target="{Binding DataContext, diagnostics:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" />
    </Grid.Resources> 
    <TextBox Tag="{StaticResource MyResObj}" />
</Grid>
```

I'm not sure resources are even aware of the logical tree though :/

Comment: Unfortunately this also does not work, it has the same binding errors. Ultimately TestObj will be a ICommand object which items not in the visual tree (like context menu items) can use which is why I am trying to bind window items to it.

Comment: Why can't you just set Tag to DataContext instead, and access that from your context menu?